# What is a good way to select random dates over a given interval using R?

Tags: r, date

I could not find a similar question so I thought it might be useful to someone else and/or generate some discussion.  I wanted to sample some daily data randomly for a quick-and-dirty validation of some processing I had done.  The question is, given an interval of start and end dates, how would one compute a vector of random dates over that interval?

Comment: There's nothing special about dates, you can still just use `sample` like with any other vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `sample.int`:

```
Start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
End <- as.Date("2013-01-31")
Samp <- Start + sample.int(End-Start, 5)
```

Comment: Even cleaner than my way!  I forgot about sampling functions.  This is the best combination of legibility and efficiency in my opinion.  Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 8):

One easy option is to generate the set of dates you want and then `sample()` from them in the usual way:

```
Start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
End <- as.Date("2013-01-31")
dates <- seq(from = Start, to = End, by = 1)

set.seed(1)
draw1 <- sample(dates, 5)
draw2 <- sample(dates, 5)

> draw1
[1] "2013-01-09" "2013-01-12" "2013-01-17" "2013-01-26"
[5] "2013-01-06"
> draw2
[1] "2013-01-28" "2013-01-29" "2013-01-20" "2013-01-18"
[5] "2013-01-02"
```

May not be the most efficient if the interval is long as you need to generate all the dates, but the code is quite clean and easy to grep the meaning of.

Comment: easy to "grep" the meaning? Too much coding for you, sir. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd use `sample`

```
dates <- Sys.Date() - 20:1
sample(dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
as.Date("1979-01-01") + 
  runif( 10, 
    max=as.integer( 
      as.Date( "2012-12-31") - 
        as.Date( "1979-01-01")))

[1] "1997-03-07" "2009-01-11" "1983-02-04" "1999-11-11" "2006-03-26"
[6] "2005-06-04" "2001-03-18" "1994-09-17" "1995-11-28" "1985-04-19"
```

Of course, this could easily be wrapped up as a function to parameterize start date, end date and length of the output vector.  The strength of this is that it only uses base functions; a shortcoming might be that it is only for whole days.  If you need greater resolution something more involved is necessary.